# Why I cannot call C++ overridden function through DLL through JVM?

Tags: java, c++

I have a staic library called "CommonUtils.lib". It also includes a class called "Standardconverter" which inherits a base class "Converter" that is not in static library.

I have another static library called "Utils.lib". It holds the base class "Converter" which is inherited by standardconverter class. This library is linked to a DLL called "Utils.dll" with a exported function "SendToClient". Inside SendToClient() function, it calls overridden function in

"StandardConverter"(CommonUtils.lib)

The 'Utils.dll" is loaded by java class through JVM and my problem is I couldn't able to call the overridden function of StandardConverter class.

```
// Utils.lib

class Converter
{

Public:

    Converter();

    ~Converter();

    virtual void SetAdditionalData();

}



// CommonUtils.lib


class StandardConverter:public Converter
{


Public:
    StandardConverter();

    ~StandardConverter();

    void SetAdditionalData();

}


// Utils.dll

//Exported function()


__declspec( dllexport) void __stdcall SendToClient()
{


    Adaptor()->GetConverter()->SetAdditionalData(); 

}


//Server.exe

Converter *pConverter = new StandardConverter();

Adaptor()->SetConverter( pConverter  );
```

During startup server sets the converter type. The same process creates the JVM and inside the Java class, it loads the Utils.dll and calls exported function SendToClient(). But here it calls the base class function and not calls the StandardConverter(). I think that it happens due the difference in address space. Actually the StandardConverter object is initialized and set from process Server.exe. But the dll loaded by JVM doesn't know about dynamic object and it always loads base class function only? Is my understanding is correct?

Somebody can suggest some solution to solve this issue and to call overrided function in standardConverter from JVM?

Comment: basically you can only call c++ calls from code compiled with the same c++ compiler.  You can't get any of that functionality from anywhere else.  This is why extern "C" exists - to do things in a standard way that can be used from other places -- but you can't do any fancy c++ stuff.

Comment: I found the issue. The issue is with the instantiation of static instance of Adaptor class from JVM. 
The adpaptor instance actually initialized at startup of server.exe process. But static instances were not visible in the DLL loaded through JVM. So re-initializing is happened for Adpator instance and it caused to loss Standard converter instance set by server process. Next I want to know why the static variables were not visibe in the address space of JVM.Anticipating your suggestions to solve this probelem.Thanks in advance.